# Calculate required sample size with R with known power and ratio of n1 to n2

Tags: r, statistical-power

If I know that `d=0.8`, `sig.level=0.05`, `power = 0.8`, `n1/n2 = 3`, how can I calculate `n1` and `n2` with the function `pwr.t2n.test(n1 = , n2= , d = , sig.level =, power = )` in [pwr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html) package in R or some other functions in R?

Comment: Why must it be *that* function rather than some other? Also, most of us being only average mindreaders, you should supply the name of the *package* you're using, not just the function name - not least because the same function name can exist in multiple packages. I presume you intend the `pwr.t2n.test` function that's in the `pwr` package... is that right?

Comment: Why is the significance level 0.95 rather than something more reasonable? Are you *really* dealing with a 95% type I error rate? It seems bizarre.

Comment: Once you sort that issue out, trial and error looks like a pretty reasonable choice. You can pin it down within a handful of trials.

Comment: @Glen_b Many thanks! 1)Sorry that I just start to learn R and thought the function is unique like built in function in Matlab. Yes. I mean pwr.t2n.test function in pwr package. And it is not necessary this function. Any function will be OK if the problem can be resolved. I should make this clear. 2) The 0.95 significant level is a mistake. Actually I would like to use 0.05 but type to fast...

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested, this sort of power analysis could be done by trial and error.

Using software, each guess takes only a moment, and you can very quickly (4 or 5 trials) track it down to the closest integer that gives at least the required power.

However, R lets you make many guesses at once.

Perhaps the easiest way to proceed is to specify a range of integer values for `n2`, then let n1=n2*3 and leave power unspecified. In the vector of returned power values, identify the smallest power greater than 0.8; that gives you the smallest `n2` you'll need.